# Float divs horizontally

Tags: css, responsive-design

I need help with css, I have this setup:

```
<div class="embedInner">
     <div class="embed_code"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et sapien. Quisque risus. Ut laoreet hendreri mi.</p></div> 
     <div class="copy"><p>COPY</p></div>                     
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h7u8J/11/

I want both child divs always to stay in single line, both left and right, and text in embed_code to be overflow:hidden and not to fall into new line, so if space become smaller than width of the parent div.

Comment: I dont understand what should happen if I will resize screen and make the width of the div lower then width of the text inside?

Comment: To me it's not clear what you really want. My best guess: Try `white-space: nowrap;` an embed_code element

Answer (score 0):

i changed your code!

i think this is what you want! [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/Hw3kH/4/)

**CSS:**

```
.embedInner{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    /*background: #333;*/
}
.embed_code{
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    width:90%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    background: #333;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.embed_code p{
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.copy{
    display:inline-block
    background: #ddd;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    right:0;
    width:10%;
    background:green;
    text-align:center;
}
.copy p{
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    float:right;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="embedInner">
    <div class="embed_code">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et sapien. Quisque risus. Ut laoreet hendreri mi.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="copy"><p>COPY</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I scale the browser this doesnt scale down.

Comment: you should add this line to `embedInner` class : `width:100%;`

Answer (score 0):

If you will provide certain width to the parent div and the embedded div, then you can achieve what you want.

```
.embedInner{
    position:absolute;
    /*background: #333;*/
    width: 100%; // newly added
}

.embed_code{
    float:left;
    background: #333;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 90%; // newly added
}

.embed_code p{
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
}

.copy {
    background: #ddd;
    float:right;
}

.copy p{
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    float:right;
}
```

Please check if it can help you. Thanks :)